# I am trying to grav meta tags of a webpage, help me to convert this into array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code by which I can fetch meta tags of a webpage. But I want to use it to fetch data from multiple pages or sites.
I have written this test code to grab metadata of a webpage but I want to grab the metadata of multiple pages at once. I am unable to do this by myself

```
<?php 
 
// Web page URL 
$url = $_POST['url'];
// Extract HTML using curl 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
 
// Load HTML to DOM object 
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
@$dom->loadHTML($data); 
 
// Parse DOM to get Title data 
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title'); 
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue; 
 
// Parse DOM to get meta data 
$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
 
$description = $keywords = ''; 
for($i=0; $i<$metas->length; $i++){ 
    $meta = $metas->item($i); 
     
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description'){ 
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content'); 
    } 
     
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords'){ 
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content'); 
    } 
} 

?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="j.php">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="https://google.com" name="url" value=""></textarea>
            <button
              class="btn btn-primary send-button"
              id="submit"
              type="submit"
              value="SEND">
              <span class="send-text">SEND</span>
            </button>
          </form>
 <?php          
echo "<table border='1'> <tr/><td width='30%'>Title: $title</td>". "<td width='30%'>Description: $description</td>"."<td width='30%'>Keywords: $keywords</td></tr></table>";

?>
```

I am trying to fetch meta of a website but I want to use array for multiple pages

Comment: Your question will be more clear if you [edit] your question to include `$data` as part of your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you specified multiple URLs in your textarea - perhaps each one on a separate line - then you could split that value into an array and loop.

So something like this at the top of your PHP code:

```
$urls = [];
if (!empty($_POST['url'])) {
  $urls = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['url'])));
}
$results = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {

  // ... then your code as before

  $results[$url] = [
    'title' => $title,
    'description' => $description,
    'keywords' => $keywords,
  ];
}
```

Then a display loop at the bottom

```
if (!empty($results)) {
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  foreach ($results as $url => $result) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='30%'>Title: " . htmlspecialchars($result['title']) . "</td>"
    echo "<td width='30%'>Description: " . htmlspecialchars($result['description']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='30%'>Keywords: " . htmlspecialchars($result['keywords']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Of course, if you've got a lot of URLs (like, more than 10), then this approach would need to be modified because it would take too long to query them in series.  You would either need to process them using a queue and background task, or perhaps fetch them simultaneously using curl's multi select functionality

Comment: Rob, please think of comments as toilet paper.  They can be disposed of by anyone without a trace.  If you have something important to add to your answer, please [edit] it instead of adding a comment.

Comment: @BalwinderHeer that is not actionable feedback.  I find this answer to be rather accurate despite the deficit of sample data.  You should update your question details.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, With a little effort I am able to use it now. You really solved a problem.